# What is Sweden's historical violent crime rate vs. immigration rate?

Tags: immigration, crime, sweden

I tried to find a historical chart of Sweden's violent crime rate and came across this:

[image: sweden violent crime rate]

Which was the first image search result: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sweden+violent+crime+rate+history+chart&iax=1&ia=images

However it's not sourced and this is different from the values here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_in_Sweden

I don't really consider burglary a violent crime - just a property crime. Anyways, I wanted to see Sweden's immigration rate as well, but couldn't find any charts with both values (crime, immigration).

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sweden+violent+crime+rate+history+chart+immigration+rate+chart&ia=web

Only this one for immigration/emigration:

[image: sweden immigration]

Comment: If you want to ask about Muslim immigration and crime that is certainly permissible. I'm just trying to clarify the question per an Indigochild suggestion, and not trying to change the question.

Comment: Using Google reverse image search (permalink too long to put here), the first mention I can find of that image is [4chan](https://archive.4plebs.org/pol/thread/42971448/) on 25th of March 2015. The only other mentions are in forum posts and the like *after* that date. In other words: looks like some 4chan troll pulled that directly out of his behind (also knows as [PIDOOMA](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/PIDOOMA)).

Comment: `couldn't find any charts with both values (crime, immigration)` -> The problem with that is, what axis do you use and what scale? Obviously they can't be the same. Also, correlation doesn't imply causation (or: lack of correlation doesn't mean lack of causation). So in that sense putting both lines on the same chart may not be as insightful you you'd think it might be and is a great way to "lie" (or be fooled, even when there is no malicious intent) with statistics.

Comment: If the chart isn't deliberately inflammatory, and the data are accurate, I'd wager that an Excel neophyte reversed the series labels by mistake. It is, after all, a vanilla Excel chart with basic/default settings.

Comment: A fair question in terms of pure data, but it'd be nice to see an actual connection between the two variables less it just sounds a bit like an attempt and connecting dots through pseudo analysis. For example, the two variables have no connection at all unless you are also taking into account something like the violent crime rate *of immigrants* specifically.

Comment: Not sure whether this is of interest to you but a couple of remarks if you want to dig into this further: (1) You have got a curve increasing linearly with time, you will find a high correlation with just about everything that has been increasing regularly over the last thirty years, kale consumption California, [fresh lemon imports from Mexico](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/econ439/2014/02/03/distinguishing-correlation-causation-key-critical-thinking/), pilgrims finishing the [Camino de Santiago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camino_de_Santiago), you name it.

Comment: So you can eyeball a curve with immigration to Sweden and reach whatever conclusion you want to reach, there is very little point in plotting one against the other or computing a correlation, if both curves go up (linearly), the conclusion is obvious. (2) The second curve you presented is immigration per year, i.e. the number of people entering the country in a given year. But what's your model of the possible link between this and other variables? People come, stab someone and then disappear within a year? I don't think so…

Comment: Whatever your theory, whether it's cultural, socio-economical or good ol' fashioned racism and no matter whether you are highly skeptical of immigration or support it wholeheartedly, you will probably agree that its effects unfold over decades. So you need to look at the [stock, not the flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_and_flow). Perhaps the number of people born abroad or the proportion of foreign citizens in the population or something more subtle, but definitely not the year-to-year changes.

Comment: (3) Finally, Sweden is not in the midst of violent gang wars or a breakdown of the rule of law. Its murder rate is still only slightly more than a fourth of that of the US. So “violent crime” is probably not what you think it is. You noted that it also covers burglaries but I would bet good money that the bulk of the increase is accounted for by rapes. And it's not a coincidence that it's happening in Sweden, for a lot of good reasons that have to do with definition and reporting and generally taking this problem much more seriously than many other countries.

Comment: Which in turn means that it's not obvious that there is any “real” increase, as opposed to increased awareness to a heinous behaviour that was already happening.

Comment: This would be reasonably on-topic on Skeptics.SE - half the Sweden questions there are similar to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The graphs in your first image are not comparing the same thing. The
Swedish red line measures the number of charges filed for violent
crime per 100,000 citizens. It looks like the source is table 1.2 from
the
report
[Kriminalstatistik 2009](https://www.bra.se/download/18.cba82f7130f475a2f18000766/1371914719581/2010_15_kriminalstatistik_2009.pdf),
but it is hard to know for sure.

The data for the American blue line comes form
the
[Uniform Crime Reporting Program](https://www.bjs.gov/ucrdata/abouttheucr.cfm). This
program was designed in 1929 to provide law enforcement agencies with
accurate data on the development of crime. The whole point of the
program was to produce statistics that were comparable year to
year.

The graphs are therefore apples to oranges and highly misleading. The
reason for the explosion in the number of charges filed are many and
varied. I won't go in this answer because it is a different topic. But
you can investigate statistics for Sweden's neighbours. They too have
ten times as many charges filed today as they did in the 1960s.

We can instead look at the total number of homicides in Sweden:

[image: Homicides in Sweden]

Note that the above graph is not per capita adjusted. It also doesn't
cover the years after 2010 which have become increasingly
violent. Here is the homicide rate for the US (per capita adjusted):

[image: Homicides in the US]

Now you might object and say "Wait a minute. Homicides != Violent
crime!" That is true and only a small fraction of all violent crime is
homicide. However, tracking violent crime is notoriously different for
many reasons, among them that definitions change. In 1960, beating
your children was legal. Today it is a violent crime. Therefore we use
homicide as a proxy for all violent crime. It has the added advantage
that it makes it hard for government agencies to fudge the numbers.

But we can also examine statistics on assault:

[image: Assault in Sweden]

The data in these graphs come from so called victim surveys. The
researches send out surveys and ask a sample of the population how
many of them have been the victim of an assault. As you can see, the
numbers haven't moved much since 1990.

I hope that answers your question. Sweden has received a massive
number of immigrants, but the amount of violent crime has remained
roughly constant or even decreasing.

Comment: Can you please explain what the different color lines mean? For those who don't speak the language.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is far more complex than a simple historical rate comparison. You can find a summary of several reports [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_and_crime#Sweden), and can access the reports by clicking the relevant links.

In short, most crimes in Sweden (~60% of them) are committed by suspects born of 2 Swedish parents. However, immigrant males are more likely to be investigated (and possibly convicted, in part due to facing discrimination from the Swedish judicial system) than ethnic Swedes---this likelihood diminishes the younger the person arrives in Sweden, the higher their socioeconomic status, and their education level.

In other words, not very different from any other society or place in the world: people with higher education, better social integration and life prospects, have little incentive to turn to violent crime.

To more directly answer your question, Nationmaster.com has an accurate and verifiable [comparison](http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/compare/Sweden/United-States/Crime) between crime in the US and Sweden, which disproves the chart in your question (given the lack of sources/data gathering methodology, etc.).

Excerpts of the main findings from those reports:

> The 2005 report by the Swedish National Council for Crime Prevention studying 4.4 million Swedes between the ages of 15 and 51 during the period 1997-2001 found that 58.9% of crime suspects were born to two Swedish parents (74.5% of total population), 10.4% of those born to one Swedish parent (9.3% of total population), 5.2% of those born to two foreign parents (3.2% of total population), and 25% of foreign-born individuals (13.1% of total population).[86] The report found that male immigrants were four times more likely to be investigated for lethal violence and robbery than ethnic Swedes. In addition, male immigrants were three times more likely to be investigated for violent assault, and five times more likely to be investigated for sex crimes.[86]
> ...

On the other hand:

> A 2006 government report however suggests that immigrants face discrimination by law enforcement, which could lead to meaningful differences between those suspected of crimes and those actually convicted.[88] A 2008 report by the Swedish National Council for Crime Prevention finds evidence of discrimination towards individuals of foreign descent in the Swedish judicial system.[25] The 2005 report finds that immigrants who entered Sweden during early childhood have lower crime rates than other immigrants.[89] By taking account of socioeconomic factors (gender, age, education and income), the crime rate gap between immigrants and natives decreases.[89]

Finally:

> A study using more comprehensive socioeconomic factors than the 1996 and 2005 reports found that "for males, we are able to explain between half and three-quarters of the gap in crime by reference to parental socio-economic resources and neighbourhood segregation. For females, we can explain even more, sometimes the entire gap."[12] The authors furthermore found "that culture is unlikely to be a strong cause of crime among immigrants".[12]

Bonus: A personal anecdote, as an immigrant in another country (i.e., not Sweden). My two brothers and I emigrated (through proper legal channels) from a developing country traditionally associated with drug dealing and other crimes, to a developed country with low crime rates. We are all bilingual/trilingual, have professional degrees, same for our partners. Here, we've met other legal migrants from our country (civil engineers, special effects animators working in blockbuster movies, etc.), who are also gainfully employed, pay their taxes, and pay into the public health care system. Many of us have had spells of unemployment, and none have turned to violent crime as a result---we do as everyone else does: update our resumes/linkedin profiles, go to job hunting sites, start looking. Others have gone back to school, gotten another credential, started a new job.

However, one of these friends (say, John) met a fellow countryman (Peter) who came here illegally. Peter had never met another migrant from our country, and poured out his soul to John: that Peter's dad brought Peter illegally when he was just a boy, he grew up under unstable circumstances, and nowadays, Peter was a drug trafficker (yes, he shared as much). John, who wanted to stay on the Law's good side, didn't want to be associated with Peter, and left the party.

So... same country, vastly different immigration and life conditions. Immigration alone doesn't increase violent crime, but unmanaged immigration (i.e., without resources devoted to promoting integration, education opportunities, and reducing discrimination/racism) will often create marginalized groups which, in times of need, can turn violent.

Comment: That comparison could need a bit more attention, because it goes completely contrary to what the image in the question says. According to nationmaster.com, The United States are still far ahead of Sweden in every category of violent crime except rape. Rape being so prominent in Swedish crime statistics might be because of the [comparably broad definition of rape in Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_in_Sweden). The Swedish law code qualifies many acts as rape which would be lesser crimes in other jurisdictions.

Comment: This is good info, but it's a snapshot. Is there a chart or table with trends and historical data?

Comment: Well, as @Carpetsmoker mentioned, correlation does not imply causation: you could easily find an increasing trend in both, yet have nothing to do with each other. Example: https://i2.wp.com/i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--DYzL3oHe--/19bm94ui3v59fpng.png

For source/explanation: https://puffthemutantdragon.wordpress.com/2015/02/21/does-organic-food-cause-autism-could-nicolas-cage-movies-make-you-more-likely-to-drown-six-ways-to-lie-with-statistics/

Comment: > unmanaged immigration (i.e., without resources devoted to promoting integration, education opportunities, and reducing discrimination/racism) will often create marginalized groups which, in times of need, can turn violent. I think I mentioned this is a different question but the host countries should be held responsible for their inability to create a conducive environment for the immigrants to remain non-violent. When the host countries fail to do that, people blame the poor immigrants. Just not fair.

Comment: Yep: humans are hypersocial creatures, strongly shaped by their social environment. Only the host country has the power to determine what that environment looks like for migrant communities. That's how Canada runs a successful immigration program: you see ads on public transit welcoming immigrants, directing them to resources and organizations to help them improve their English, get more education, find community support, etc. My wife volunteers at one of these governmental organizations, where she supports migrant parents to integrate and raise kids in Canadian culture.

Comment: @Klashir 99% of all Canadian immigrants at the very least received a tourist visa to get into the country. Completely incomparable to (say) Germany where a million people entered without any vetting.

Comment: Hence, my comment amount unmanaged immigration, and the Peter/John story. It is unfortunate that Merkel's good-will was not matched with good execution: the fallout has little to do with the immigration rate (which the charts in the question are discussing), and more to do with the tragedy of war, and the torrent of displaced.